# Independence of an event and a sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

We defined the independence between events and also the independence between sigma algebras. What about an event is independent with a sigma algebra?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *What about...*

Comment: Let $E$ be an event and $\mathcal F$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. We say $E$ is independent of $\mathcal F$ if $P(E\cap F)=P(E)P(F)$ for all $F\in \mathcal F$.

Answer (score 0):

You can define independence of collections of sets:
[image: Klenke]

This is from Klenke's probability theory book. All other definitions of independence can be viewed as special cases of this one.